# Authentification for an API in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication

I have a working Ruby On Rails application which is accessible to web-clients. This application allows different users to work on shared projects with different credentials. Clients can login *via* a classic login/password combo to be able to access the projects they are assigned to. The credentials are stored and managed through ruby sessions by authlogic. Everything works quite well.

We wanna add an API to this application using rails MVC goodness. That means reusing the existing and working controllers and simply writing new (XML in our case) views.

This API should be easily accessible from a Java Desktop program. More specifically, and problematic, the same Java Desktop Instance may execute multiple quasi-simultaneous calls to the API, but where each call is associated with a different user.

That means we can't (I think) use the "login once, do everything approach". We need to give the login information, or at least some king of token, at every request.

Do you see a key point I am missing ? If not, do you see any way to implement this properly, or have any leads (like docs or google search queries) that coud lead me there ?

I must also add that I am absolutely not a "senior ror programmer". I am just learning the framework by working on it so don't assume I neglected an obvious solution, I may have overlooked it.

Also, don't hesitate to correct any mistake or false assumption I may have made. I really need to learn more about web programming/ruby on rails/computer science in general.

Thank you Stack O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a HTTP-based authentication scheme, like Basic Access authentication or Digest authentication.  Authlogic will automatically try to validate every request if credentials are sent in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what might help you is [`devise` gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). It is widely used for the same purpose as yours.

From its README:

> ### Devise
>
> Devise is a flexible authentication solution for Rails based on Warden. It:
>
> - Is Rack based;
> - Is a complete MVC solution based on Rails engines;
> - Allows you to have multiple roles (or models/scopes) signed in at the same time;
> - Is based on a modularity concept: use just what you really need.